# Font rendering in Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

As the question suggests, I am having an issue with all of the text on my page appearing differently in Microsoft Edge compared to Google Chrome.

However, I would like to keep / use the rendering shown in Edge.

Using JS and/or CSS, is there any way to use the styling in Edge (font family, size, etc.) and apply it in Chrome. I know it sounds silly, but the entire page from the description text to the fields appears far nicer in Edge, and more readable. So, if possible, I would love to somehow use the stying that Edge applies to the page.

The link to my page is: https://donorbox.org/youthminds.

I have included screenshots below of how it looks in Chrome and Edge.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZpLW.jpg (Google Chrome) and https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA5PY.jpg (Microsoft Edge).

Comment: try to open that page in Edge and Chrome. Than try to use developer tools of both the browser and check the difference for fontfamily, size etc. than you can make changes in your css file may help to render similar styles for Chrome. If possible than you can also try to post a small sample code which can produce the issue. we can try to provide suggestions to render same styles for both browsers.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I dug through the CSS using developer tools on Edge, but I was not able to find the styling that Edge uses to change the text. I know for Chrome, you can simply find it by eventually looking for the user agent stylesheet, but I just don't know where to and how to find anything in Edge.

On part of the CSS, I did find that Edge overrides / crosses out the CSS from the website, but I couldn't find what it changes it to.

Comment: Simply try to select the element from developer tools in Edge will display the applied css on right side in a separate side bar. like this. https://i.postimg.cc/nL2kxWBy/101.png

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I tried that in both Chrome and Edge. I used the inspect element for one of the paragraphs of text, and in both browsers, the CSS on the right sidebar appeared to be the same.

Comment: Can you please try to provide a small sample code block which can produce the issue. We can try to test it to check the result.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I am not able to without posting the code for the entire page, because the rendering is affecting all of the text on the page, and I am not sure which piece of code exactly is being affected by Edge because I cannot find it. I included two screenshots in the question, so you can see the page appears differently and nicer in Edge compared to Chrome, and the link to my page is there as well (https://donorbox.org/youthminds) so you can open it to see everything.

Comment: We cannot check the code for whole page. If you can show a sample code than we can provide some suggestions for that.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Which piece of code do you need to see?

Comment: Post the code which can show the difference in styles in both Edge and Chrome.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT

I cannot find the code that shows the difference. When I used the developer tools in Chrome and Edge, the code appeared the same. That is why I posted the question, I am not able to find the styling that Edge applies to the page, and I can't find the difference in the code.

Please check the screenshots I have posted and you will see there is a difference, but I am not able to locate the different code. In both browsers, the code appeared the same.

Comment: Check your CSS code whether multiple fonts had applied or not. If one font is not available or not supported by the browser than it can use alternative fonts may cause this issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT

I checked that, and there is only one font, and it is the same thing for both browsers. There is no difference in the CSS code. `body {
    background: #e6e7e8;
    color: #898989;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    cursor: default;
}`

Comment: I try to check on my side in Edge and chrome and both gives similar results. Output with Edge: https://i.postimg.cc/2js6xFKv/edge.png Output in Chrome: https://i.postimg.cc/jj3qnzfD/chrome.png I did not see any difference in fonts or style. you can find a little difference in spacing. Both browsers use different browser engine can be the reason for that.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT . There must be something wrong or different with my OS or browsers, because on my side, all of the text appears clearer and more readable in Edge. If you look at the second page of the form (just select any dollar amount and click next) on Chrome, the font for the 'Choose Your Province' dropdown appears different than the other fields. But if you look at it again on Edge, all of the font is the same .

Comment: I did not seen any issue with the text readability. I made this test on Microsoft Edge 44.17763.1.0 One reason can be the display settings. I am using night mode with low brightness.

Comment: Can you check the 'Choose Your Province' field on the second part of the form on Chrome? If you look at the font for that field, and compare it to the other fields, it is not the same. But if you open the same thing on Edge, all of the form fields are the same, including the province field.

Comment: This is the test result of that part. https://i.postimg.cc/qMZp0ggk/re.png If you are talking about some textboxes shows the brighter text than it is due to different browser engine. you will not be able to display that effect in chrome.